# How to border bottom the div content on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on react to display some images at the top with labels, and when I click on any of the I mage I want to show a border-bottom.

I am successfully doing this but the issue with the styling **CSS**

When I am showing css it is not showing at the bottom but at all image bottom it is showing up, which is breaking the alignment

**I am using bootstrap for better UI**

**My code**

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="form-inline">
    {d.map((li, index) => (
       <div key={li.name} onClick={() => img_click_handler(index)}>
         <img src={li.url} alt={li.name} className="image_class" />
         <div className="label_name text-left">{li.name}</div>
         <div className={index === index_id ? "test" : ""} />
         </div>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.App {
  min-height: 17.6vh;
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #00000040;
  opacity: 1;
}

.image_class {
  height: 7vh;
  width: 4vw;
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.label_name {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  width: min-content;
}

.test {
  border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**Issue**

The issue is the `border` bottom I want to show to the end of the bar `div` but it is showing up to image bottom

[Please check this Code sandbox for working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-euler-jwwkw?file=/src/styles.css:0-329)

** I want border bottom should come to the ending of the bar I don't know what I am doing wrong**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a changed [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-greider-im63y)

I added `d-flex` instead of `form-inline` and `d-flex flex-column` for each column div.
For the bottom line i added an auto margin with `mt-auto`.
To have a margin on the top i added `mt-3` to the image.

There may be a better solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add absolute position to test div to achieve your requirement.

Please add following css

```
.test {
  border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-inline {
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Test link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-jackson-ogqco